# Finite groups with the same presentation are isomorphic, has the 'same' center and conjugacy classes?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

I was considering the following group:

$G = \langle(12),(1425)\rangle \leqslant S_5.$

If we call $s = (12)$ and $r=(1425)$, obviously we have $r⁴=1=s²$.

Also, we can see that $srs^{-1} = (2415) = (1524) = r^{-1}.$

So $G$ satisfies the same presentation as $D_4 = \langle x,y:x⁴=y²=1,yxy^{-1}=x^{-1}\rangle.$

Those relations must give us $G = \{1,r,\cdots,r³,s,\cdots,r³s\}$ and similarly for $D_4$. Hence we can construct an explict isomorphism given by
$\phi : \; G \rightarrow D_4$ by $r^is^j\mapsto x^i y^j$.

Also, it follows that the centers are isomorphic. It gives us that $Z(G)= \{1,r²\}, $ since we have $Z(D_4)$ = {1,x²}.

Also, by calculations I could see that the conjugacy classes for $G$ are:

$\{1\}, \{r²\}, \{r,r³\},\{s,r²s\},\{rs,r³s\}$, which are the same as $D_4$.

So,

my questions are: Is this always true in general?

**Two groups with the same presentation are always isomorphic?**
**do they have the same center and conjugacy classes?**

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> So $G$ satisfies the same presentation as $D_4$

Be careful! You've shown that it has two generators ($r$ and $s$), and that those generators satisfy a bunch of relations ($r^4 = s^2 = 1$ and $srs^{-1} = r^{-1}$). This is enough to show that $G$ is isomorphic to *some quotient of* $D_4$. (Use the first isomorphism theorem: map $x$ to $r$ and $y$ to $s$, and show that this map gives a surjective homomorphism.)

But there's one thing you haven't checked: are you sure $r$ and $s$ don't satisfy any *extra* relations? (Equivalently: what's the kernel of this surjective homomorphism?)

It turns out that they don't, by the way (i.e. this homomorphism is also injective). But you need to check that.

> Two groups with the same presentation are always isomorphic?

Yes.

> do they have the same center and conjugacy classes?

Isomorphic groups have the same *everything* - except that their elements might be called different things.

Comment: Great answer. I would add only that in general it is often *very* difficult to check that some presentation is indeed a presentation of a given group, there is no general recipe and one should not rush into such conclusions.